# How do I change the default color of the canvas in QGis 3.4?

Tags: qgis

The default color is white. How may I switch it to another color ? To be clear, I'm talking about the background, not the menus, nor panels or toolbars, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Settings menu > Options > Canvas & Legend

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can change the color of the map canvas and many other GUI items with [User Interface Themes](https://nathanw.net/2015/08/29/ui-theme-support-now-core-in-qgis/).

Comment: As a side note, this probably only affects new projects. For existing projects you can change the background color under menu Project | Properties, General (first option on the left).